# Replace function doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have imported a mySQLi database and all worked fine except that I have now a `'\r\n'` everywhere in my columns (where there were a newline).

I have tested all I could find on google and unfortunately I didn't succeed.
The Replace I want to do is simple :

```
UPDATE llx_societe_alarme
SET historique = REPLACE(historique, '\r\n', CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
```

It works but affect 0 line
Can you help me with that ? Thank you !

Comment: Just to clarify: you have, in your data, the string literal '\r\n' and you are wanting to replace that with a real carriage return and line feed?

Comment: Could it be that your database client is showing you \r and \n instead of actual char(13) and char(10)? (so you actually don't have '\r\n' as part of the value for the fields)

Comment: Do you mean `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)` or do you mean `CONCAT(CHAR(13), CHAR(10))`?

Comment: `\r\n` is a [special character escape sequence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) You may need to enable `no_backslash_escapes` run the update and then disable it again. or perhaps use `\\r\\n` so the system knows not to escape the `\r\n`

Answer (score 1):

`REPLACE(txt, '\\r\\n', CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))`  seems to eliminate the \r or \n's and substitute the char(13)+char(10) correctly.

Why? `\r` or `\n` is a special escape character sequence so the \ needs to be escaped.

**Doc Sources:**

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html (escaping)
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes (change the SQL mode so that no `No_backslash_escapes` is enabled)

.

1. DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3771a/1/0 (just select no update)
2. DEMO2: http://rextester.com/RYMIZ68964 (running update)

**Using rextester for an update:**

The update works.  (I had to switch from SQL fiddle it kept timing out on me).  This to me implies:

1. A server setting somewhere
2. You have data that I'm not testing with which results in the 00.

Please update my rextester.com example above with data that results in the 00. Maybe there are other non-display characters or other values causing this issue.  I'm after a [MCVE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjwuZCtyoHWAhWH7YMKHUjECFcQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fmcve&usg=AFQjCNHreFGjawnJ-ucm2EGso8qxNscnMA) since I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: The '\\r\\n' worked but it is now replaced by '00' insteed of a carriage return

Comment: odd... the SQL fiddle demo doesn't do that.

Comment: Now that I replace the '00' + 2 next characters with CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 2 next characters, It deletes the '00' and the next 2 characters...

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3771a/5/0 shows that the ASCII value of the right most character is 10  when it needs to be. very odd...  Until I can recreate the 00 issue not much chance of me being able to help.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Could it be a problem with the type of my column, like "varchar" or "text" or something like that ?

Comment: more like to do with [character sets and collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html) Do you know what the table and database are setup as?

Comment: I say that because I'm unable to recreate the issue in the SQLFiddle environment showing the 00.  Implying there's something else going on; which to me means initall setup/configuration or collation/character sets.

Comment: I found this parameter : Connection Character Sets and Collations:utf8mb4_unicode_ci. Could it be that ? Also, charset of the server is : UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: Doesn't seem like that would be a problem: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166405/why-are-we-using-utf8mb4-general-ci-and-not-utf8mb4-unicode-ci.  maybe I actually need to try an update statement vs just the select in my example.  http://rextester.com/RYMIZ68964 shows it working (I had to switch fiddle kept timing out on me).  This to me implies a server setting somewhere. Can you try and recreate using my example?  maybe there are other non-display characters involved in your sample that after our update are getting rendered differently.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, to be clear I have '\r\n' in a lot of fields, I also have '\n\n' or '\r' or '\n' everywhere that I had a carriage return before moving my database. I just want to remove it and put a carriage return.

Example, I had :

- Line 1
- Line 2
- Line 3

Now I have :

- Line 1\r\n- Line 2\r\n- Line 3

Or in some case :

- Line 1 
  \r\n- Line 2
  \r\n- Line 3

and other examples where it is just '\r' or '\n' or '\n\n'

It is visible in my client and also on my website.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, in MySQL 5.6,  is doing

```
UPDATE table
SET txt = REPLACE(txt, '\\r\\n', "\r\n")
```

This gave me real carriage returns.  The "\r\n" sequence inside a double-quoted string seems to give real carriage returns, and the '\r\n' finds the string versions properly.

You can also do a

```
SELECT txt, REPLACE(txt, '\\r\\n', "\r\n") 
FROM table
```

to troubleshoot your results before running the actual update.